# Can Eigen use more than Double precision in its linear algebra Ax=b

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I am using Eigen to do some linear algebra. i.e. find x in Ax=b. Where A is (n,n) matrix and x and b are (n,1) size vectors. I would like to know if it is possible to compute them with more than double precision.

Comment: As in `long double`? If so, that's built in: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html#CustomScalarType

Comment: It's linear math. If you first calculate `A * x0 = b`, you can next calculate `A * x1 = (b - A * x0)`, then add x0 and x1.

Comment: You can also use [boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) number types, or [mpreal](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__MPRealSupport__Module.html).

Answer (score 1):

Eigen can work with arbitrary precision arithmetic. There is [an MPFR module](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__MPRealSupport__Module.html) readily available. Usually, this should not be necessary though (unless your original values already are stored in that high precision). You should first try using a more stable decomposition. Have a look [at the available decompositions here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html). Which one is best, heavily depends on your use case.